# Distinguish which field has changed in signal.instance , Django/signals

Tags: django, django-signals

Lets say I have a model called BookModel with 4 fields : (title, author, price, publish_year).

And I have a handler in signals:

```py
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=BookModel)
def signal_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
…..
```

Question is how to distinguish a situation when specific model field has changed during save(). For example if price has changed  I want to do stuff. Better explain in pseudo code...

```py
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=BookModel)
def signal_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
# pseudo code bellow
if field “price” has changed:
    do stuff
else:
    do nothing
```

According the docs if I use “update_fields” in save() - it is possible, but what if I dont use it???

Also is it possible to distinguish a situation when I received signal from post_save or from post_delete still using 1 handler?

```py
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=BookModel)
def signal_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
# pseudo code bellow
if signal is post_save:
    if field “price” has changed:
        do stuff
    else:
        do nothing
else:
    do other stuff
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker)'s FieldTracker to track changes in model fields. It also use with `post_save` signal.

> Checking changes using signals
>
> The field tracker methods may also be used in pre_save and post_save signal handlers to identify field changes on model save.

Comment: Thanks. That is an option. Question on how to distinguish 2 post_save and post_delete in one handler is still open though